# How to copy a file from one directory to another with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to copy an excel file from one folder to another one. But, everytime it copies it, I want to change the name to TABLEAUPCQ1, TABLEAUPCQ2, TABLEAUPCQ3, and so on..

the reason is, I cant overwrite the excel file if someone is already using it in that other path..

```
Sub CopierFichier()

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Call fso.CopyFile("R:\ASP\PCQ_BEHESP\SuiviPCQAssignations\TABLEAUPCQ.xlsm", "V:\DGI\11000_Surveillance\11200_InstallationsSousPression\PCQ\Suivi\TABLEAUPCQ.xlsm")

End Sub
```

Comment: For that you have to implement some sort of counter as integer and include the integer into your filename like e.g. `Call fso.CopyFile("R:\ASP\PCQ_BEHESP\SuiviPCQAssignations\TABLEAUPCQ" + integer_var + ".xlsm"`

Comment: @Phanti it's not working :/

Comment: There is a built in VBA function to do this. `FileCopy "SourceFilePathHere", "DestinationFilePathHere"`. Also, if you are looking to replace the file you are copying to the destination, you can use the overwrite paramter of CopyFile. Set the last parameter as `true`. E.g. `fso.CopyFile "FirstPath","SecondPath",true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the counter by 1 after each sub execution within a cell value. That way you have the current count stored outside your function.

Grab it, use it, increase it.

```
Sub CopierFichier()

Dim counter_var As String
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

counter_var = Cells(1, 1).Value

Call fso.CopyFile("R:\ASP\PCQ_BEHESP\SuiviPCQAssignations\TABLEAUPCQ.xlsm", "V:\DGI\11000_Surveillance\11200_InstallationsSousPression\PCQ\Suivi\TABLEAUPCQ_COPIE_" + counter_var + ".xlsm")

Cells(1, 1).Value = Cells(1, 1).Value + 1

End Sub
```

I corrected the small error.

Comment: it's giving me error 13 at this line 
Call fso.CopyFile("R:\ASP\PCQ_BEHESP\SuiviPCQAssignations\TABLEAUPCQ" + integer_var + ".xlsm"

Comment: try again with `Dim counter_var as string`

Comment: Just like the code you wrote above? I copy pasted the whole block, it's not working..

Comment: ''File not found'', everything is correct, idk why they say the file is not found..

Comment: ohhh we wrote counter_var at the wrong place, now it's working :)

Comment: counter_var should go at destination path and not source